# Fully invariant submodule and maximal submodule

Tags: ring-theory, modules, invariant-theory

Let $M$ as a $R$-module and $N\subset M$ a fully invariant submodule of $M$. Why the exists a maximal submodule of $M$ such as $L$ that $L\cap N=\{0\}$.

Definition: We refer $N$ as a fully invariant submodule of $M$ if for every homomorphim $\varphi : M\to M$ we have $\varphi(N)\subset N$.

Comment: The "fully invariant" condition on the submodule contributes nothing and the statement is perfectly true for *all* submodules of any submodule $M$. The resulting maximal submodule is an essential submodule of $M$.

Answer (score 1):

Zorn's Lemma: define

$$C:=\left\{\,K\le_R M\,\;/\;K\cap N=\{0\}\right\}$$

since $\;\{0\}\in C\;$ we have that $\;C\neq\emptyset\;$ , and it's easy (do it) to see $\;C\;$ is partially ordered by set inclusion and fulfills the conditions on any chain in it , so it has a maximal element...

Comment: So where did use the fully invariant of $N$ in this proof?

Comment: Nowhere at all: it is either idle data or else that will be used in some other application or problem.

Comment: @DonAntonio Please, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I interpret the wording of the question as saying: If $N$ is a fully invariant submodule of $M$ then there is a maximal submodule of $M$, call it $L$, such that $L\cap N=\{0\}$.
This claim is false:

Consider $M:=\mathbb{Z}$ as a module over itself ($R:=\mathbb{Z}$). Any $R$-endomorphism $\varphi$ of $M$ is determined by the image of $1$, since if $\varphi(1)=n$ then $\varphi(m)=\varphi(m\cdot 1)=m\varphi(1)=mn$. Therefore

$$\varphi(\mathbb{Z})=n\mathbb{Z}$$
and
$$\varphi(k\mathbb{Z})=kn\mathbb{Z}\subset k\mathbb{Z}.$$
Thus all ideals of $\mathbb{Z}$, which are precisely its $R$-submodules, are fully invariant. On the other hand we have
$$k_1\mathbb{Z}\cap k_2\mathbb{Z}=\text{lcm}(k_1,k_2)\mathbb{Z},$$
which is nonzero unless $k_1=0$ or $k_2=0$. In particular, all nonzero fully invariant submodules have nontrivial intersection with all maximal submodules (which are those $p\mathbb{Z}$ with $p$ prime).

Comment: In this case $\;L=\{0\}\;$ is the maximal submodule of $\;\Bbb Z\;$ wrt the condition that $\;L\cap N=\{0\}\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio I see now the problem. I don't interpret the OP (whose wording seems confusing to me) as saying that $L$ should be maximal relative to the condition, but as saying "there exists a maximal submodule of $M$, call it $L$, such that $L\cap N=\{0\}$". Is it easy to interpret in the other way? I just don't see how (apart from perhaps knowing that this is an exercise in some books, which then would not include the fully invariant condition).

Comment: Tal vez tengas razón. La manera de escribir la pregunta es confusa, por el mal uso del inglés. Yo lo entnedí como maximal con respecto a....